# Merge array elements group by properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following javascript object array:

```
       [ { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "age": 10}, 
         { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "height": 100},
         { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "weight": 50},
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "age": 11}, 
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "height": 110},
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "weight": 60},
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "age": 12}, 
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "height": 120},
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "weight": 70}]
```

Is it possible to group by firstName and lastName such that it includes other properties of the object in the array?

Expected Array:

```
       [ { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "age": 10, "height": 100, "weight": 50}, 
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "age": 11, "height": 110, "weight": 60},
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "age": 12, "height": 120, "weight": 70}]
```

Comment: Assume it is possible, have a go, and then edit this question with a [mcve] of that effort.

Comment: I would recommend reading about and trying: [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I think you may need to look at "sorting functions" but I'm not entirely clear on what you need as output.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Ok, I can do this via for loop for each element but it wont be a generic solution for each properties. I will still give a try and post an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Concept**

Prepare a result array. Iterate through all the data. Check if the `firstName` and `lastName` exist in the result array. If no, push it into the result array. If yes, merge the object to get the missing properties.

**Code**

```js
const data =[ { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "age": 10}, 
         { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "height": 100},
         { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "weight": 50},
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "age": 11}, 
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "height": 110},
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "weight": 60},
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "age": 12}, 
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "height": 120},
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "weight": 70}];
let result = [];
let found;
data.forEach(d => {
  found = false;
  result.forEach(r => {
    if (r.firstName === d.firstName && r.lastName === d.lastName){
      Object.assign(r, d);
      found = true;
    }
  });
  if (!found){
    result.push(d);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something exactly like this. I didnt know Object.assign can merge the properties. I was doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
const group = data => Object.values(data.reduce((res, {firstName, lastName, ...rest}) =>{
  const key = JSON.stringify({firstName, lastName})
  
  return {
    ...res,
    [key]: {firstName, lastName, ...(res[key] || {}), ...rest}
  }
}, {}))



const data = [ { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "age": 10}, 
         { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "height": 100},
         { "firstName": "x", "lastName": "y", "weight": 50},
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "age": 11}, 
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "height": 110},
         { "firstName": "a", "lastName": "b", "weight": 60},
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "age": 12}, 
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "height": 120},
         { "firstName": "m", "lastName": "n", "weight": 70}]
         
console.log(group(data))
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still trying to understand but it works!

Comment: Pure code answers without explanation is a real PITA, and doesn't really *help* anyone.